# Back up/ Restore in sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013

We have a Production environment where our production url is working fine. But unfortunately we don't have a copy of same in development environment. so we are planning to take a back up from production and restore it in development . I tried using Backup from central administration and got the back up files but not sure how to proceed. As the restore, gives option to restore to the same database.

Can someone guide me how to set up my dev environment

Please note Sql Environment is controlled by third party so we dont hav control over that

Answer (score 1):

http://lmgtfy.com/?q=backup+restore+sharepoint+2013

Joke aside, Technet is full of guides regarding how to make backups and restore of the parts of a SharePoint installation.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee662536.aspx will guide you right.

Here is some best practices: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg266384.aspx

Comment: Hi Robert, Thanks for your response. Actually i followed the above article from technet and took the back up using Central administration but the problem here is When i click on Restore using Central administration it is showing the same url from which i took the back up

Comment: My tip is to use powershell for all types of backup restore work. It gives you a much greater control over the process and the granularity

Comment: Hi Robert, tried with powershell using Export-SPWeb & Import-SPweb. It was successful but when i tried to open the list it throws error that list does not exist. "Unexpected error when trying to resolve virtual path '~masterurl/custom.master' for basePath '/Pages/default.aspx' in request 'http://Pages/default.aspx': 'List does not exist.  The page you selected contains a list that does not exist."

Comment: Check this Powershell commands Backup and Restore process    Backup-SPSite -Identity http://productionserver -Path "c:\backup\file.bak"      For Restore     Restore-SPSite -Identity http://devserver -Path "c:\backup\file.bak"

Comment: Hi Nagaraju, sorry for late reply. I used the above powershell commands and missed to update in the forum.It worked !!!